# Count of unique nested values in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, count, nested

I have a schema that looks like this and I would like to get the `journal` which mentions the maximum number of unique `drugs`.

```
    my_list = [{'atccode': 'A04AD',
  'drug': 'DIPHENHYDRAMINE',
  'mentioned_in': [{'date': '01/01/2019',
                    'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing'},
                   {'date': '01/01/2019',
                    'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing'
                    },
                   {'date': '1 January 2020',
                    'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing'
                    },
                   {'date': '1 January 2020',
                    'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing'},
                   {'date': '1 January 2020',
                    'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing'
                    }]},
 {'atccode': 'S03AA',
  'drug': 'TETRACYCLINE',
  'mentioned_in': [{'date': '02/01/2020',
                    'journal': 'American journal of veterinary research'
                    },
                   {'date': '2020-01-01',
                    'journal': 'Psychopharmacology'}]},
 {'atccode': 'V03AB',
  'drug': 'ETHANOL',
  'mentioned_in': [{'date': '2020-01-01',
                    'journal': 'Psychopharmacology'
                    }]},
 {'atccode': 'A01AD',
  'drug': 'EPINEPHRINE',
  'mentioned_in': [{'date': '01/02/2020',
                    'journal': 'The journal of allergy and clinical '
                               'immunology. In practice'},
                   {'date': '01/03/2020',
                    'journal': 'The journal of allergy and clinical '
                               'immunology. In practice'
                    },
                   {'date': '27 April 2020',
                    'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing'
                    }]}]
```

So the result will look to something like this :

```
    {
         "journal":"Psychopharmacology",
         "unique_drug_mentions" : 2
    },
    {
         "journal" : "Psychopharmacology",
         "unique_drug_mentions":2

    }
```

What I've been trying so far is

```
from collections import Counter

mentions_counts = Counter(d['journal'] for d in my_list)
most_common = {'unique_drug_mentions': mentions_counts.most_common(1)[0][0], "journal" :d["journal"]}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: What does it mean for a drug to be "unique" in your specification ?

Comment: @joao I mean there will be no duplicate count of  it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and supply more sample input data and the desired output resulting from processing it.

Comment: "no duplicate count of it" isn't specific enough. Count of the drup per journal, in all of them, or what? Again show some more varied input and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just loop through my list:

```
# store counts of unique drugs here
counts = {}

# loop through your dicts in the list
for d in my_list:

    # look in each journal mention
    for d2 in d['mentioned_in']:

        # if we haven't seen this journal before
        if d2['journal'] not in counts:
            counts[d2['journal']] = set()

        counts[d2['journal']].add(d['drug'])

# this would have all your verbose info as you want it
unique_drug_counts = [
    {
        "journal": journal,
        "unique_drug_mentions": len(drugs)
    }
    for journal, drugs in counts.items()
]

# max value (the answer to your question
max(counts.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
```

Comment: Whoops, had a typo, updated to your naming of my_list

Comment: I've tried it but it gives me as count all of them 1

Comment: well in your test data set the unique count is 1 for both journals, no? Have you tried it on a larger set?

Comment: I've updated my question with the right data and output

Comment: hmmm, it looks right to me, this is my output: ```[{'journal': 'Journal of emergency nursing', 'unique_drug_mentions': 2},
 {'journal': 'American journal of veterinary research',
  'unique_drug_mentions': 1},
 {'journal': 'Psychopharmacology', 'unique_drug_mentions': 2},
 {'journal': 'The journal of allergy and clinical immunology. In practice',
  'unique_drug_mentions': 1}]```